# sending DNS queries asynchronously with asyncio and dnspython

Tags: python, dns, coroutine, python-asyncio, dnspython

Say I want to send various types of DNS queries (A, AAAA, NS, SOA, DNSKEY, NSEC3, DS, etc) for Alexa top 1M sites using dnspython.

Doing this one by one would take a bit long, since I'm sending multiple queries for each single site. So I wish to perform some parallelism using asyncio in python 3.

I went through David's generator/coroutine trilogy, http://www.dabeaz.com/talks.html, but I'm still not sure how to finish my simple task...

More specifically,

```
results = dns.resolver.query('google.com','AAAA')
```

is a blocking function call, waiting for the DNS reply to come back.

How can I send other queries during this waiting time without using Threads? Since DNS queries are usually udp packets, I thought asyncio might help.

pycares seems not supporting all record types I need, so pycares and aiodns do not work for my case.

Any references and ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately if `aiodns` and `pycares` doesn't satisfy your needs you should use synchronous `dnspython` library. You may execute it in thread pool by `res = yield from loop.run_in_executor()`.

Just for curiosity: what DNS records are not supported by `pycares`?

Comment: Are you familiar with asyncio? David's generators and coroutine slides are really good, but a lot of this work is done for you in asyncio, where you basically use an event loop and run your blocking code with 'yield from'. Thus other code can run in the meantime.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov As I mentioned in the question post, I need to perform some DNSSEC related queries, like DNSKEY, DS. They are not supported by pycares.

Comment: @shongololo what's the relationship between using thread pool and event loop? Were they the same idea?

Comment: @Eniaczz with asyncio you can use thread pools if you want via run_in_executor() but you don't need to use them. For your situation it seems the relevant concept is that the various 'yield from' points provide opportunities for asyncio to switch back and forth between various coroutines / tasks whilst waiting for blocking code to run.

Comment: Have a look at the unit test: https://github.com/saghul/aiodns/blob/master/tests.py

Answer (score 6):

As of recently, DNSPython now has native AsyncIO support, though the [documentation is a little lacking](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async.html).

Nevertheless, it's now possible to query using dnspython without needing hacky threadpool solutions.

### AsyncIO DNSPython Example

Below is a simple example of using dnspython's AsyncIO `Resolver` class using a wrapper function, and `asyncio.gather` for bulk querying efficiently:

```py
from dns.asyncresolver import Resolver
import dns.resolver
import dns.rrset
import asyncio
from typing import Tuple


async def dns_query(domain: str, rtype: str = 'A', **kwargs) -> dns.rrset.RRset:
    kwargs, res_cfg = dict(kwargs), {}
    # extract 'filename' and 'configure' from kwargs if they're present
    # to be passed to Resolver. we pop them to avoid conflicts passing kwargs
    # to .resolve().
    if 'filename' in kwargs: res_cfg['filename'] = kwargs.pop('filename')
    if 'configure' in kwargs: res_cfg['configure'] = kwargs.pop('configure')

    # create an asyncio Resolver instance
    rs = Resolver(**res_cfg)

    # call and asynchronously await .resolve() to obtain the DNS results
    res: dns.resolver.Answer = await rs.resolve(domain, rdtype=rtype, **kwargs)

    # we return the most useful part of Answer: the RRset, which contains
    # the individual records that were found.
    return res.rrset


async def dns_bulk(*queries: Tuple[str, str], **kwargs):
    ret_ex = kwargs.pop('return_exceptions', True)

    # Iterate over the queries and call (but don't await) the dns_query coroutine
    # with each query.
    # Without 'await', they won't properly execute until we await the coroutines
    # either individually, or in bulk using asyncio.gather
    coros = [dns_query(dom, rt, **kwargs) for dom, rt in list(queries)]

    # using asyncio.gather, we can effectively run all of the coroutines
    # in 'coros' at the same time, instead of awaiting them one-by-one.
    #
    # return_exceptions controls whether gather() should immediately
    # fail and re-raise as soon as it detects an exception,
    # or whether it should just capture any exceptions, and simply
    # return them within the results.
    #
    # in this example function, return_exceptions is set to True,
    # which means if one or more of the queries fail, it'll simply
    # store the exceptions and continue running the remaining coros,
    # and return the exceptions inside of the tuple/list of results.
    return await asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=ret_ex)


async def main():
    queries = [
        ('privex.io', 'AAAA'),
        ('privex.io', 'TXT'),
        ('google.com', 'A'),
        ('google.com', 'AAAA'),
        ('examplesitedoesnotexist.test', 'A'),
    ]
    print(f"\n [...] Sending {len(queries)} bulk queries\n")
    res = await dns_bulk(*queries)
    print(f"\n [+++] Got {len(res)} results! :)\n\n")

    for i, a in enumerate(res):
        print("\n------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        if isinstance(a, Exception):
            print(f" [!!!] Error: Result {i} is an exception! Original query: {queries[i]} || Exception is: {type(a)} - {a!s} \n")
            continue
        print(f" [+++] Got result for query {i} ( {queries[i]} )\n")
        print(f"  >>>  Representation: {a!r}")
        print(f"  >>>  As string:")
        print(f"    {a!s}")
        print()
    print("\n------------------------------------------------------------\n")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here's what the output looks like when you run the above script:

```
 [...] Sending 5 bulk queries


 [+++] Got 5 results! :)



------------------------------------------------------------

 [+++] Got result for query 0 ( ('privex.io', 'AAAA') )

  >>>  Representation: <DNS privex.io. IN AAAA RRset: [<2a07:e00::abc>]>
  >>>  As string:
    privex.io. 221 IN AAAA 2a07:e00::abc


------------------------------------------------------------

 [+++] Got result for query 1 ( ('privex.io', 'TXT') )

  >>>  Representation: <DNS privex.io. IN TXT RRset: [<"v=spf1 include:spf.messagingengine.com include:smtp.privex.io -all">, <"google-site-verification=_0OlLdacq3GAc4NkhOd0pBcLsNya3KApS0iAc6MtbYU">]>
  >>>  As string:
    privex.io. 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.messagingengine.com include:smtp.privex.io -all"
privex.io. 300 IN TXT "google-site-verification=_0OlLdacq3GAc4NkhOd0pBcLsNya3KApS0iAc6MtbYU"


------------------------------------------------------------

 [+++] Got result for query 2 ( ('google.com', 'A') )

  >>>  Representation: <DNS google.com. IN A RRset: [<216.58.205.46>]>
  >>>  As string:
    google.com. 143 IN A 216.58.205.46


------------------------------------------------------------

 [+++] Got result for query 3 ( ('google.com', 'AAAA') )

  >>>  Representation: <DNS google.com. IN AAAA RRset: [<2a00:1450:4009:80f::200e>]>
  >>>  As string:
    google.com. 221 IN AAAA 2a00:1450:4009:80f::200e


------------------------------------------------------------

 [!!!] Error: Result 4 is an exception! Original query: ('examplesitedoesnotexist.test', 'A') || Exception is: <class 'dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN'> - The DNS query name does not exist: examplesitedoesnotexist.test. 


------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Background tasks using AsyncIO

Assuming your application is purely AsyncIO, then it's possible to run coroutines in the background, without needing threads:

```
import asyncio

async def hello():
    for i in range(10):
        print("hello world")
        await asyncio.sleep(2.0)

async def lorem():
    for i in range(20):
        print("lorem ipsum dolor")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)


async def my_app():
    print(" [...] creating tsk_hello and tsk_lorem")
    tsk_hello = asyncio.create_task(hello())
    tsk_lorem = asyncio.create_task(lorem())

    # let them both run for 5 seconds
    print(" [...] waiting 5 secs")
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)

    # now, assuming you wanted to cancel a looping task before it's finished
    # (or tasks that are endless 'while True' loops)
    # we can use the tsk_x task objects to ask them to stop immediately.
    print(" [...] stopping tsk_hello")
    tsk_hello.cancel()
    print(" [...] waiting 4 secs")
    await asyncio.sleep(4.0)
    print(" [...] stopping tsk_lorem")
    tsk_lorem.cancel()

asyncio.run(my_app())
```

If you run the above example code for AsyncIO background tasks, the output will look like this, showing that both `lorem` and `hello` are able to run side-by-side, along with the main entrypoint function:

```
 [...] waiting 5 secs
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolor
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolor
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor
 [...] stopping tsk_hello
 [...] waiting 4 secs
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolor
 [...] stopping tsk_lorem
```